# Does jQuery .on("click") always run before <a> href fires?

Tags: jquery

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    doSomething();
});
...
<a href="http://website.com">My Link</a>
```

Will `doSomething()` always run before the "href", in every browser?

Comment: Yes. If there is an event bound to click then its return value controls if there is a subsequent navigation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, your handler will run always first. That's what allows you, for instance, to cancel default behavior (navigate to href url) if necessary

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // --> if this handle didn't run first, this wouldn't work
   doSomething();
});
```

Comment: so to clarify, even if the `e.preventDefault()` came at the very end of the handler, after LOTS of code, it would still cancel the href fire?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case though if, in your click function, you are say pushing tracking info to another server. Using Fiddler, I see nothing being pushed before the link is followed. Using OnClick always seems to do the push, then follow the link. Using on and click always seems to follow the link without pushing data elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does. If you don't want the href to fire you can call `e.preventDefault();` and the browser won't follow the link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only the part that runs before the first `await`:

```
$("a").on("click", async function(e) {
  example(); // this will always run

  await Promise.resolve();

  example3(); // this may not run, as it is after the first `await`, and it is after nagivation
  e.preventDefault(); // this does not work, as it is after the first `await`
});
```