# Make sure jQuery on click runs before a href firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to make sure jQuery on click event executes before the user is forwarded to the external URL? I have been googling now for 2 hours and read a couple of posts here on stackoverflow. I just cant get this to work.

This is what I've tried:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" class="external-url">Click me</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.external-url').on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

    if (myCustomEvent()) {
      window.location = this.href;
    }
});

function myCustomEvent()
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Execute some custom JS here before a href firing...');
        return true;
    }, 3000);
}
```

But it seems like the line "if (myCustomEvent()) {" is exectuted before myCustomEvent function is able to return true. Is there a better way to do this? And a way that actually works?

Comment: Your selector in `$('external-url')` is incorrect, you are using an attribute selector when you should be using a class selector. I assume that is a typo.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219822/does-jquery-onclick-always-run-before-a-href-fires

Comment: you can also look for events like onbeforeunload. But this will not work in Safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery click event *does* run before the location changes--but you're doing something async in the middle of the click handler.

The easiest thing to do would be to pass in what you want to have happen into `myCustomEvent`, roughly:

```
$('.external-url').on('click', function (e) {
  const url = this.href
  
  e.preventDefault()
  
  myCustomEvent(function() {
    window.location = url
  });
});

function myCustomEvent(fn) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Execute custom JS before firing navigation...');
    fn();
  }, 3000);
}
```

There are other ways to handle this depending on your actual requirements.

Comment: Wow finally! This did the trick, works great! Thank you so much!