# How can I use Javascript to display a message to mobile users to please use a larger screen?

Tags: javascript, mobile, screen-size

I have a landing page that is optimized for all screen sizes, but it contains an "Enter" button that takes the user to content that is not optimized for mobile devices. I want to attach a script to the Enter button that will deliver a message if a user is on a mobile device along the lines of "Please explore this project on a larger screen."

Currently I have the Enter link tagged as an "enter" id (<a id="enter" href="http://...), and this is my script, which doesn't seem to be working:

```
<script>
// returns true if current device is a mobile device
window.mobileAndTabletCheck = function() {
  let check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};

    var modal_options = {"minHeight":200, "minWidth":400, "overlayClose":true, "autoResize":true}


    $('#enter').click(function() {

        if (window.mobilecheck()) {
            $.modal("Please explore this project on a large screen", modal_options);
            return false;
        }
    }})
    </script>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please create a proper [mre]. Also, the `}})` at the end is likely supposed to be `})` edit: nevermind, the function is called `window.mobileAndTabletCheck` and you're calling `window.mobilecheck()`

Comment: (plus I'd use something like `window.innerWidth < 769`)

Answer (score 1):

The name of your function and the function you're calling are not the same. And rather than use a giant regex to try to guess if the screen is large enough based on user agent, you can check `$(window).width() > 1024` (or whatever size), which will be much more maintainable.

Comment: Thank you! Silly mistake on my part with the function name. Fixed that but still not working. Does my jquery file need to have certain click actions defined? My JS skills are pretty basic, so if there's an alternative way to get the result I'm looking for that doesn't involve jquery I'd be very interested.

Comment: Your click handler on the a tag runs before navigation, but if the issue is that navigation happens before the modal pops up, you may need to call `preventDefault` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16219898/5774952).